# How to convert data into JSON dictionary?

Tags: python, json

So I get a response and print it. The result is bytes:

```
payload = request.body
print (payload)
b'a=123&b=345&c=678&d=910'
```

I decode it, and the result is:

```
dataform = payload.decode('utf-8').replace("'", '"')
print(dataform, 'dataform')
a=123&b=345&c=678&d=910
```

I dumps it, and the result is:

```
result = json.dumps(dataform, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
print(result, 'result')
"a=123&b=345&c=678&d=910"
```

I loads it, and the result is:

```
jason = json.loads(result)
print(jason, 'jason')
a=123&b=345&c=678&d=910
```

I just want a normal json dictionary that I can refer to like data['string']. What am I doing wrong or not doing?

Comment: The string doesn't contain any single quotes, so replacing them is superfluous (and if it wasn't, it'd be wrong). Other than that, are you looking for `d = dict(x.split('=', 1) for x in payload.decode('utf-8').split('&'))` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few errors here.

First off, dumping to JSON and then loading it again does absolutely nothing (it does have a few side-effects, but that's not important here).

Secondly, and mainly, your input data isn't JSON - it's either a query string or, more likely, form-data.

You can try to parse it using the standard `parse_qs` in `urllib.parse`, but if that fails you'll have to look around for a library that can handle proper form data.

```
In [1]: from urllib.parse import parse_qs

In [2]: payload = b'a=123&b=345&c=678&d=910'

In [3]: dataform = payload.decode('utf-8').replace("'", '"')

In [4]: result = parse_qs(dataform)

In [5]: print(result)
{'a': ['123'], 'b': ['345'], 'c': ['678'], 'd': ['910']}
```

Comment: The `.replace()` part is superfluous. Also in python2, you should do `from urlparse import parse_qs`.

Comment: the parse_qs is what I needed. Thanks. I did not know of that.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

payload = request.body
# b'a=123&b=345&c=678&d=910'

qs = parse_qs(payload.decode())
# {'a': ['123'], 'b': ['345'], 'c': ['678'], 'd': ['910']}
```

Convert list values and convert data into JSON

```
json.dumps({k: v[0] for k, v in qs.items()})
# '{"a": "123", "b": "345", "c": "678", "d": "910"}'
```

Comment: An explanation, what the posted code does and how this addresses the problem in the question, rarely fails to improve an answer.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you need to convert the string (here, as the example, to the array, but you can use that you want)

```
data = [x.split('=') for x in data.split('&')]
>>> data
[['a', '123'], ['b', '345'], ['c', '678'], ['d', '910']]
```

And after this, you can easily create the dictionary.

```
dict = {key: value for (key,value) in data}
>>> dict
{'a': '123', 'c': '678', 'b': '345', 'd': '910'}
```

Or if you want to store numbers as int:

```
dict = {key: int(value) for (key,value) in data}
>>> dict
{'a': 123, 'c': 678, 'b': 345, 'd': 910}
```